# Re-using SQL instance for multiple farms

Tags: database, sql

During a transition phase of indeterminate length, I will be hosting the databases for a SP2012 farm and an unrelated SP2013 farm on the same physical hardware. I know that the guidance for mixing SP and non-SP loads is to have SP in a separate instance(MAXDOP et.al.). Is it ok to mix db's from different farms, assuming I have a good naming convention(AutoSPInstall to the rescue)?